# Boolean function minimization for more than 100 variables

Tags: circuit-design, boolean-algebra

I need to minimize boolean functions with more than 100 variables.
Additionally, each row has some don't care conditions.

### For example,

```
  | A | B | C | D ........................| Y |
  _____________________________________________
  | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 ........................| 1 |
  | 1 | 1 | 0 | X.........................| 1 |
  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.........................| 0 |
```

In the previous example if the first 3 bits are "110" then we don't need to consider other bits.
Though the number of variables is 100, the number of row entries are very small, around 3000.
I know about K-map and Quine-McCluskey algorithm which works very well for a small number of variables. There are some programs which can minimize such expressions with less than 16 variables. But I have heard there exist faster and better algorithms to minimize such circuits which electronic engineers use for circuit minimization. Unfortunately, I was not able to find such program which will take my inputs and their respective outputs and provide a minimized boolean expression. Or in short I need a boolean expression in the end.
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Quine-McCluskey should work for 4+ number of variables but another algorithm which is faster is called the Espresso algorithm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer

Comment: I don't know if it can handle so many variables (haven't tried to do that many), but you might download and try out "Logic Friday." http://www.sontrak.com/ It uses Espresso to do the work. (Never mind. Just tried it to see. Limited to 32 variables, I think. At least, when entered in table form.)

Comment: https://trinket.io/python/fbbf7518b8  you might also use this script which uses QM

Comment: for what purpose are you doing this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm lazy.

I often let compilers and the such do my work.

Thus, I'd recommend you find a language in which you can formulate logic values, and then optimize them.

This is the core problem of Hardware Description Language (HDL) synthesizers, as used for FPGA and digital IC design.

Hence, HDL synthesizers are exactly the type of program you're referring to.

Thus, I'd simply take my table, and convert it to a set of conditions in verilog (a popular HDL).

Then, I'd use the *excellent* [Yosys](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/about.html) to parse, optimize and emit in one of many formats (including graphical representation or a gate level net list) my logic.

That's pretty easy, actually:

```
module thing_to_be_simplified (input [399:0] in, output [12:0] out)
    if(in[2:0]==0b'110) then
       out = value;
    else if( ... ) 
       ...
endmodule
```

Convert your table to such a cascade of `else if`s with a simple python script.

Then I'd run `yosys`, do the `read_verilog` command on my verilog source code, run a `check`, run an `opt` (optimization), and then `show` (to see a graph of gates) or `write_verilog` (or `write_<otherformat>`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am going to try this method. Is there any chance that I get the output as an expression, for example, Y=A'BC'D+ABC'D......+A'B'C'D.

Comment: yep. When you eg. generate Verilog, you'll get wires, and these will correspond to your input and intermediate, repeatedly used terms.

Comment: I tried yout method with a simple code. My functions are F=AB+AC; G=A'b+A'C.
module xor_and_or(input [2:0] i,output [1:0] e);
 always
  begin
   if (i == 3'b000) e = 2'b00;
   else if (i == 3'b001) e = 2'b01;
   else if (i == 3'b010) e = 2'b01;
   else if (i == 3'b011) e = 2'b01;
   else if (i == 3'b100) e = 2'b00;
   else if (i == 3'b101) e = 2'b10;
   else if (i == 3'b110) e = 2'b10;
   else e = 2'b10;
  end
endmodule

I followed your instructions accordingly. The write_verilog outputs  a file with cascaded case blocks instead of minimized expressions. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

A great way to solve this problem is to use the open source tool espresso.  The problem with the Quine–McCluskey algorithm is that it really doesn't scale well with more inputs (100 is a fair bit of inputs).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer

This is an open source tool which was created by a university.  It uses a heuristic algorithm to (very efficiently) reduce large boolean expressions.

It is also what is used (under the covers) for logic minimization in many industry standard tools.

A little more info here: [How can I convert multiple Karnaugh maps into a logic gate circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260333/how-can-i-convert-multiple-karnaugh-maps-into-a-logic-gate-circuit/260686#260686)

Comment: thank you for your help. I used Espresso, but it only does two level optimization. Is there any other tool which can do multi-level optimization?

Comment: That would be synthesis tools like ABC which implement a function in terms of the logic gates in the library (based on whatever constraints you give it).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you help me with a tiny example? Maybe with a simple XOR-gate. I am sorry I have no experience with electronics and hardware compilers.

Comment: You would describe the XOR functionality and enter it as an expression.  The synthesis tool will choose gates in your library (which you must provide; for example it may include NAND, NOR, NOT in a few different drivestrengths each) and implement the function described by your expression.  You can also give it a truth table.